# Oracle Equivalent of SAS First.Variable action

Tags: sql, oracle

recently need to self learn SQL.

Coming from a SAS background, I am looking for an equivalent of:

```
data output_set;
  set input_set;
  by REF Location;

  if first.REF then FIRST_REF = 1;
run;
```

Trying to construction something equivalent in SQL. I know briefly about FIRST_VALUE() to output the first row. but not quite doing the same thing.

```
select
  REF
  ,Location
  ,case when FIRST_VALUE(REF) then FIRST_REF=1
from input_set
;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of the SAS code is:

```
select is.*,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by ref order by location) = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
from input_set is;
```